# Golang code organization for multi-platform multi-language project

Tags: go, organization, code-organization, project-organization

I am looking for a good project organization for a multi-platform project with multiple components written in Go. I am aware of the recommended layout from http://golang.org/doc/code.html, but the layout suggested there does not seem to fit my requirements.

Project components are:

- server (written in Go)
- client, cross-platform (Go)
- library, shared between server and client (Go)
- some more clients (iOS, Android)

My requirements are:

- All components in a single git repository
- Keep components separate (e.g. one directory per component)
- Go components can be structured into multiple sub-packages

My current approach:

```
project/ (this is the repository root)
  server/
    server.go (package main)
    src/          
      server/
        package1/
          package1.go
        ...
  client/
    client.go (package main)
    src/
      client/
        package2/
          package2.go
        ...
  lib/
    src/
      lib/
         lib.go
         ...
  client-ios/
    ...
  client-android/
    ...
```

To build, I use a Makefile which

1. Copies lib/ into both server/ and client/
2. Builds server/ and client/ separately, setting GOPATH every time to the respective directory.

It works, but feels really klunky and is quite different to the recommended code layout.

Here is the alternative I am considering:

```
project/ (this is the repository root)
  gospace/
    src/
      server/...
      client/...
      lib/...
  client-ios/
    ...
  client-android/
    ...
```

With this layout I have a single GOPATH (gospace/) and don't need the klunky Makefile. However, the components are not separated as neatly as in the first alternative (i.e. via a top level directory).

My question: Which project layout would be best suited for both my requirements and Go conventions and tooling support? Are there better options which I did not see yet?

Comment: Why not `$GOPATH/src/gospace/{server,client,lib,ios,android}`. The typical GOPATH structure is $GOPATH/{src,bin,pkg}. This way it's easy to just `go build gospace/server` or `gospace/client` from anywhere on your GOPATH.

Comment: That's a good alternative as it puts all components on the same level. It feels a bit odd to put ios and android inside the Go workspace, under the src dir. ios and android have their own sub-directory structure with their own src dirs etc. and are unrelated to Go.

Comment: You can checkout your repo under GOPATH (path will be like  GOPATH/src/project/{gospace,client-ios,client-android}). Since go will not touch client-* directories until you ask him to do that, they will happily live together in that directory. As a bonus, your project become `go get`able.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I organized a similar project :

```
$GOPATH/src/project-root/
    lib.go
    lib_test.go

    server/
        server.go
        server_test.go

        main/
            server.go // package main; import "project-root/server"

    client/
        client.go
        client_test.go

        main/
            client.go //package main; import "project-root/client"

    client-ios/
        ....

    client-android/
        ....
```

While mostly having `server/server.go` and `client/client.go` as `package main` should work, it's better to separate it so you could embed the client/server in other projects.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since this question was answered (last comment on OP was Feb. 12, 2014, and the latest answer was Apr. 16, 2014). I wasn't around for the state of Go at that time, only really being introduced to it in 2018/19, yet it looks like a lot has changed.

The biggest change that influences the answer to this post, I believe, is Go Modules.

I have a similar project in the works (Go server, Go CLI, Android app, iOS app). I am currently using go version go1.13.7 darwin/amd64. Here is the structure I came with via Go Modules (very much influenced by [this post by Ben Johnson](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1)):

```
directory-outside-GOPATH/
    go.mod
    go.sum
    domaintypes.go
    cmd/
        api/
            main.go
        cli/
            main.go
    postgres/
        ...(library Go code)...
    http/
        ...(library Go code)...
    android/
        ...(Android app)...
    iOS/
        ...(iOS app)...
    ...(other Go code).../
        ...
```

The root directory sits outside of the GOPATH and includes the necessary `go.mod` and `go.sum` files. The `domaintypes.go` file is to illustrate that the only Go files I leave in the root directory is code that will never import anything else - such as defining your domain types/models/service-interfaces/etc. I personally have multiple: `user.go`, `group.go`, etc.

The `postgres` and `http` directories are libraries I have written, both of which are layered adapters. Each library directory should be isolated to its domain. e.g. HTTP routes should not directly interact with database connections.

The `cmd` directory is where all executable Go code should live. I want an API server and a separate CLI so this is where that lives. These files should remain relatively small and call all of the other libraries you wrote.

As for the non-Go code, I simply created separate directories in the root directory for both Android and iOS.